# Which unit is Gazebo using when publishing to joint_states?

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I'm wondering which unit Gazebo is using when publishing to the topic joint_states. According to the message definition it could be (for the velocity) rad/s or m/s.
I would appreciate any hint about that.

BR, Florian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400757/which-unit-is-gazebo-using-when-publishing-to-joint_states?/) by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2022-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Fetullah Atas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32821/fetullah-atas/) on 2022-05-17**:
whats the type of joint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As per ROS REP 103: Standard Units of measure and Coordinate Conventions, units in Gazebo should be specified in meters and kilograms. (...)

https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html

It seems to depend on the controller:

http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control#Controllers

https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/4205/joint_state-ros-topic-from-gazebo-and-ros_control/

and the joint type being controlled (http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint):

> (required only for revolute
> and prismatic joint)
>
> An element can contain the following
> attributes:
>
> - lower (optional, defaults to 0)
>
> An attribute specifying the lower joint
> limit (radians for revolute joints,
> meters for prismatic joints). Omit if
> joint is continuous.
>
> - upper (optional, defaults to 0)
>
> An attribute specifying the upper joint
> limit (radians for revolute joints,
> meters for prismatic joints). Omit if
> joint is continuous.

---

Originally posted by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) with karma: 3064 on 2022-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-05-19**:
Thanks. In the model I am working with right now a JointVelocityController (http://wiki.ros.org/robot_mechanism_controllers/JointVelocityController) is used. The type of the joint is 'continuous'.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-19**:
Is the joint in the robot prismatic or revolute?

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-05-20**:
It's of type continuous.

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-20**:
What does it mean? Linear motion? Or rotational?

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-05-20**:
According to http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/XML/joint a continuous joint is defined as follows:
a continuous hinge joint that rotates around the axis and has no upper and lower limits

Each wheel of the mobile robot has a joint of the mentioned type. It is used to apply linear velocity (in terms of revolutions per second).

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thank you for the clarification. It will be rad/s then

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thanks! =)

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-05-20**:
You may accept this answer so the question will be marked as solved

**Comment by [florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/97892/florian/) on 2022-05-20**:
I marked the answer as correct. This is what you mean, right? ... Sorry, I am a bit of a newbie in this forum.